# I am trying to create a list that "updates" the position of a value on a button input

Tags: python

Basically I am trying to create a snake game using only the terminal, not because its particularly fun, of efficient (I know there are MUCH better ways to do this) but to get used to working with and understanding python as I am just a beginner.

```
import keyboard

dirx = 1
diry = 0

x = 0
y = 0


a = ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-']

def getkey():
    global x
    keyboard.wait('d')
    x +=1

while True:
    # creates a constantly updating list, which will function as part of the game board
    a[x] = 0
    a[not x] = '-'
    print('\r', a, end='')
    getkey()

    if x > 4:
        x = 0
```

This is where I've gotten to and I've hit a bit of a road block, I can get 0 to move along just fine but getting the rest of the positions to update back to '-' is a lot more difficult, not x kinda worked but it stopped after going past 0, I think its not accounting for the updated value but I'm not sure. It's probably a very simple solution but again I'm just learning, and I cannot figure this out

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly "not x" is not a proper way to select all list elements except x. `not x` just checks whether x is True (i.e. != 0) or not and then negates this outcome.

Hence, the only outcome of `not x` is either True or False, which then gets translated into 0 (the first element) or 1 (the second element) during indexing.

To avoid this, you have a couple of options. The "brute force" way would be to fully reconstruct the list in each loop:

```py
import keyboard

x = 0

def getkey():
    global x
    keyboard.wait('d')
    x += 1

while True:
    a = ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
    a[x] = 0
    print('\r', a, end='')
    getkey()

    if x > 4:
        x = 0
```

For "advanced indexing" I would consider looking into [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html) arrays.